# Own configuration properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-config

Following chapter 5 of [Spring in action fifth edition](http://mocom.xmu.edu.cn/home/project/soft/Spring/Spring%20in%20Action,%205th%20Edition.pdf) I have tried to establish my own confuguration variables with spring boot:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myprops")
public class MyClass {

    private int myvar1;

    // Getters and setters...
}
```

Written in file `application.properties` only this:

```
myprops.myvar1=3333
```

`MyClass.getMyvar1()` should return `3333` now but it still returns the default int value: `0`.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Demo1Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Demo1Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner foo(ApplicationContext ctx) {
        return args -> {
            MyClass mc = new MyClass();
            int x = mc.getMyvar1();
            System.out.println(x);
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: no :( I have added `@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyClass.class)` under `@SpringBootApplication`

Answer (score 0):

Add [@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyClass.class)](https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot) to `Demo1Application`

> If we don’t use @Configuration in the POJO, then we need to add @EnableConfigurationProperties(ConfigProperties.class) in the main Spring application class to bind the properties into the POJO: